# How to load static data when rails app loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 4.0, is there a way to load from the database once at startup and have it available throughout the application? For instance, I have an app with goods and services categories. In my navbar partial, I need the `@goods` and `@services` variables available to populate the drop-down menus. Currently, I'm querying the database on every page load in `ApplicationController` and setting those attributes, but the categories (almost) never change so this seems dumb.

Answer (score 0):

One major point of HTTP is that it is stateless, so giving it a state doesn't seem right to me.

I suppose the simplest answer is to store the categories in the session.

Comment: Okay, I think maybe I was just over-thinking on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Create an initializer and use constant.
E.g. config/initializers/contsts.rb

PRODUCT = Product.all
etc

Comment: In Rails 4, this is supposed to be done in `application.rb`. But there I don't have access to my `ActiveRecord` classes. Any suggestions?

Comment: in the bottom of application.rb file you need to add this code. or better create initializer, it's better to keep your application.rb clean